# Extent print area when data table gets more rows

Tags: excel, printing

I have a data table and a print area, they look like this:

[image: Print area + data table]

As you see, the print area is currently set to the borders of the table (plus one line at the top). Now when the data table is filled, the print area is not extended. How can I go ahead and have the print area automatically extended?

It is annoying that it's not doing it automatically. If I put the print area to a certain range, it automatically prints every single potential page (I have repeat the header row).

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Is there anything else on the sheet apart from the table?  Do you want to print the whole table or just some of it?

Comment: There is nothing else beneath the table and I want to print the entire table (plus one row above).

Comment: Have you tried deleting the print area and printing with the header row (plus the extra row) set to print on every page? Is that an Excel table because row 6 doesn't look like it has any data and may even be merged?

Comment: It has no data now, because it hasn't been filled yet. I update the Connection query and then it gets filled but the range doesn't adjust. I've tried your way and it then prints the first couple of rows which I don't want to be printed.